# Какой командой можно закрыть все открытые приложения в андроид?

Tags: android

Какой командой можно закрыть все открытые приложения в андроид?

Существует ли в Андроид какая нибудь команда которая позволяет программно закрыть все открытые приложения, даже те которые видно при нажатии на кнопку меню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это маловероятно. Если вашему приложению будет не хватать памяти, Android сам принимает решение об уничтожении запущенных приложений по мере надобности по приоритету, также учитывая сколько какое приложения потребляет памяти в фоне.

**UPD**

Кажется это возможно, но это плохая практика. Вот ссылка на пример:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11667080/1836605

Comment: А вы не встречали такое приложение? я бы в самом коде тогда глянул бы. Но все же я думаю что есть способ реализовать такое. Все таки это простой код. Да стандартные спосбы не позволяют это. Но ведь есть же другие способы.

Comment: @xTIGRx Обладая root правами скорей всего можно какой либо командой убить процессы, т.к. можно будет выполнять обычные shell команды. На устройстве без root так сделать точно не получится.

Comment: @temq, отлично. Дайте мне код как убить процессы все тогда. пожалуйста

Comment: Это как раз он и есть. Разве не работает?

Comment: @iamtihonov, Почему плохая практика?

Comment: система должна сама принимать решение о уничтожении фоновых приложений